Using the DY-HV20T module with rp pico in UART
I'm trying to make this little MP3 player (dy-HV20T) work.
The module works in autonomous mode, but impossible to communicate with it in UART.
Here is the test code:
from machine import UART, Pin
from time import *

uart1 = UART(1, baudrate=9600, tx=Pin(4), rx=Pin(5))
uart1.init(9600, bits=8, parity=None, stop=1)
busyPin = Pin(3, mode=Pin.IN)

while True:
    uart1.write(b'\xAA\x02\x00\xAC')
    uart1.read()

And the link to the module document that lists the UART orders: DY-HV20T datasheet
This code is supposed to read the mp3 present on the sd card, but no sound comes out.
Connections:
DY-HV20T      RP-Pico
TXD (IO0) -->  RX1 (GP5)
RXD (IO1) -->  TX1 (GP4)
GND       -->  GND


Can you confirm your command using USB-TTL serial chip first? Also, it would be helpful if you share your wiring.

I don't know what the USB-TTL command is? If you ask if the module works in standalone mode, yes it works (e.g., the module plays when connecting IO0 and GND).

If you ask if the connection between the pc and the rp pico works, the answer is yes, I checked with the blink test code.

I mean testing it using a tool like CP2102 USB-TTL converter(in your computer command-line without Raspberry Pi). Make sure the module is powered on. Why you are using a loop while True:? You should run the command once.

Ah, ok, but I don't have a USB-TTL converter. The while true is because I did different tests, and I left it, but it doesn't change anything, it doesn't work either if I launch the command only once

Finally I managed to play the player with this code (the problem actually came from a false contact of a Dupont wire of the GND):
from machine import UART, Pin
from time import *

uart1 = UART(1, baudrate=9600, tx=Pin(4), rx=Pin(5))
uart1.init(bits=8, parity=None, stop=1)
# Play
uart1.write(b'\xaa\x02\x00\xac')
# query play status
uart1.write(b'\xAA\x01\x00\xAB')
# query current song
uart1.write(b'\xAA\x0D\x00\xB7')
uart1.readline()
sleep_ms(10000)
# Stop
uart1.write(b'\xAA\x04\x00\xAE')
# query play status
uart1.write(b'\xAA\x01\x00\xAB')
uart1.readline()

I have the 1st song that starts for 10 seconds, then stops, but I have no answer from the code Query play status, and query current song...
